# How launch spy-js on windows 8

Tags: javascript

How can I launch spy js (http://spy-js.com/) on windows 8 ? I did all steps from http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/675-how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-windows-7/ to configue proxy.

Address: localhost
Port: 3546

Than save this setting and click Start and Open from spy-js in system tray. I use Chrome and after all actions before, it is not working still in browser. Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

First, have a look if the page you're trying to trace is https secure page. Tracing https websites is not supported at the moment.

Then, make sure traced website scripts are not cached in browser, hit Ctrl + R or Ctrl + F5 on the page you're trying to trace (clear the cache if required).

Also tracing JavaScript inlined into HTML pages is not supported at the moment, only JavaScript in separate script files.

If it still doesn't work, could you share the URL you're trying to trace here or in project public github repository issues?

P.S. You shouldn't need to manually configure proxy settings on windows for chrome if you're using tray application.

Comment: I checked the log file and saw "Can not start node.exe, please make sure nodejs is installed". But I have node.js installed.

Comment: Try manually configuring network proxy settings to use spy-js URL (host localhost, port 3546) like [described here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/675-how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-windows-7/) and running `node spy.js` from command line.